# The "award bounty" button is indistinguishable from the "bounty awarded" indicator in the mobile site

Tags: feature-request, bounties, mobile-web

*This post has examples from blender.SE but I think all sites use the same theme on mobile (through the browser, not the SE app).*

I've recently offered a bounty on a question. Then I visited the page on mobile and I thought I had mistakenly awarded it! There was a blue <kbd>+150</kbd> under an answer!

I then realized that on mobile there is no distinction between the "award bounty" button and the "bounty awarded" indicator:

[image: Comparison on mobile]  ←  *mobile*

On desktop, at least in Blender.SE, the difference is highlighted by the color of the box:

[image: Comparison on desktop]  ←  *desktop*

and the mouse-over tooltip also helps removing any ambiguity.

Should this difference be highlighted on mobile as well?

Comment: My bad for the duplicate, I didn't search well enough